# Dojo build 1.7 built packages does not work

Tags: javascript, build, dojo

I'm at the beginning of building my project and I get some errors that couldn't realize why they are being occured.

You can see contents of `my app.profile.js` file below. I execute 
`"build profile=../../app.profile.js -r"` this line from command prompt and I get no error after the process is done. My problem is if I copy the release(built) version of these packages to the place where the unbuilt versions exist, I get too many javascript errors like "`Error: multipleDefine`". Even if I copy only dojo, dojox and dijit folders, same errors are keep occuring.

When I look the differences between built and unbuilt of two js files, (for example dojo/Deferred) the only difference I realize is this:

```
//built 
define("dojo/Deferred", [ 
        "./_base/lang", 
        "./promise/CancelError", 
        "./promise/Promise" 
], function(
```

---

```
define([ 
        "./_base/lang", 
        "./promise/CancelError", 
        "./promise/Promise" 
], function(
```

So I'm a little bit stucked at the beginning. I want to try using layers to reduce http requests as soon as possible but I need some help about the situation I mentioned. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

app.profile.js:

```
var profile = { 
    basePath: "..", 
    layerOptimize: "shrinksafe.keepLines", 
    optimize: "shrinksafe", 
    releaseDir: "./release", 
    hasReport: true, 

    packages: [ 
        { 
            name: "dojo", 
            location: "./dojo" 
        }, 

        { 
            name: "dijit", 
            location: "./dijit" 
        }, 

        { 
            name: "app", 
            location: "./app" 
        }, 
        { 
            name: "dtk", 
            location: "./dtk" 
        }, 
        { 
            name: "dojox", 
            location: "./dojox" 
        } 
    ], 

    layers: { 
        "app/layers/core": { 
            include: [ 
                        "dojo/_base/declare", 
                        "dtk/core/ILifeCycle", 
                        "dtk/core/AppConfig", 
                        "dtk/core/TopicContext", 
                        "dtk/core/NavigationContext", 
                        "dojo/require", 
                        "dojo/_base/Deferred", 
                  "dojo/DeferredList", 
                        "dojo/_base/lang" 
            ] 
        }, 
        "app/layers/appcontext": { 
            include: [ 
                "dtk/core/AppContext" 
            ], 
            exclude: [ 
                "app/layers/core" 
            ] 

        } 

    } 
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The Dojo builder will add a module identifier to every module definition unless you tell it not to.  This can produce the *multipleDefine error*.

From the [builder documentation](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.7):

> **insertAbsMids (default = undefined)**
>
> - **[truthy]** Causes the transform to ensure that every AMD define
>     application includes a module identifier argument.
> - **[falsy]** The
>     transform does nothing to the module identifier argument in define
>     applications. In particular, a falsy value doe not cause the
>     transform to remove a module identifier argument that exists in the
>     source code.

I was having exactly the same problem until I added ***insertAbsMids***:false to my profile.

eg:

```
var profile = {
    basePath: "./",
    releaseDir: "release",
    action: "release",

    layerOptimize: "shrinksafe",
    optimize: "shrinksafe",
    cssOptimize: "comments",
    mini: false,
    insertAbsMids: false,

    packages: [
        { name: "dijit", location :"dijit" },
        { name: "dojox", location :"dojox" },
        { name: "dojo", location :"dojo" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is with the id that gets created in the AMD module define(id, [deps], factory)..
I was having a similar issue, I had to manually remove all the id's on the compressed files:

```
//built 
define([ 
        "./_base/lang", 
        "./promise/CancelError", 
        "./promise/Promise" 
], function()
```

OR, I had to require the module using the id instead.

For example, I was requiring a module:

```
require(["app/Dialog"])
```

which was different than the id added.

```
require(["demo/app/Dialog"])
```

It was the only way I got it to work. Anyone else knows how to remove the id or reason why we should always have an id? Not sure if this is relavent to your question, but since you showed the differences.

Answer (score 1):

This will build a layer, requiering all modules needed to create the dojox.image.Gallery *besides* the components mentioned in the discardLayer.

```
    layers: [ {
                    name: "../dojox/discardLayer.js",
                    discard: true,
                    dependencies: [
                            "dojox.image.Gallery",
                            "dojox.image.SlideShow",
                            "dojox.image.ThumbnailPicker"
                    ]
            },{
                    name: "../drops/layer.js",
                    layerDependencies:  [ "../dojox/discardLayer.js" ],
                    dependencies: [
                            "dojox.image.Gallery"
                    ]
```

Try instead of `exclude`, use the `layerDependencies` key - i think the exlude looks for app/layers/core from withing your dojo_source tree and not in dojo_release tree.. So at time of build youre excluding an unknown component.

The above sample is something i've used to be able to override the 3 discarded components elsewhere, however it doesnt suit your needs.

You would need to **Not** set `discard` for your **core layer** and instead simply set it as a dependency (which will exclude all dependencies to the layers, which has allready been built).

Then, depending on which version of dojo youre using - you should call `dojo.require("layers.core"); dojo.require("layers.appcontext")` or `require(["layers/core", "layers/appcontext"], function() {  });` to assert that those layers are present.

Before using anything from their dependencies, pull in the requirement with another require call, e.g. `dojo.require("dijit.form.Button"); new dijit.form.Button({ ... });`. The layer will fill the components into a cached hash (dojo.cache) and to make sure theyre declared fully, pull in the requirement.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400194/dojo-build-dojo-require-still-needed

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I'm changing my layer considering your reply. But another thing is when I remove the whole layers section from my profile and build it, then replace the built version of dojo, dojox and dijit to non-built ones, I'm still getting js errors. So I think that it's not about the mistakes in layers section am I thinking wrong?