# Dojo 1.9 build 'multipleDefine' error while loading locale

Tags: dojo, locale, nls, dojo-build, dojo-1.9

My dojo application breaks after building, during loading the app, throwing 'multipleDefine' and giving this error:

> Error {src: "dojoLoader", info: Object}

Message: multipleDefine

> info: Object {pid: "dojo", mid: "dojo/nls/dojo_en-us", pack: Object,
>   url: "dojo/nls/dojo_en-us.js", executed: 5…}

Here is my profile:

```javascript
var profile = {
// `basePath` is relative to the directory containing this profile file; in this case, it is being set to the
// src/ directory, which is the same place as the `baseUrl` directory in the loader configuration. (If you change
// this, you will also need to update run.js.)
basePath: '../src/',

// This is the directory within the release directory where built packages will be placed. The release directory
// itself is defined by `build.sh`. You should probably not use this; it is a legacy option dating back to Dojo
// 0.4.
// If you do use this, you will need to update build.sh, too.
// releaseName: '',

// Builds a new release.
action: 'release',

// Strips all comments and whitespace from CSS files and inlines @imports where possible.
//cssOptimize: 'comments',

// Excludes tests, demos, and original template files from being included in the built version.
mini: true,

// Uses Closure Compiler as the JavaScript minifier. This can also be set to "shrinksafe" to use ShrinkSafe,
// though ShrinkSafe is deprecated and not recommended.
// This option defaults to "" (no compression) if not provided.
optimize: '',

// We're building layers, so we need to set the minifier to use for those, too.
// This defaults to "shrinksafe" if not provided.
//layerOptimize: 'closure',
layerOptimize: '',

// Strips all calls to console functions within the code. You can also set this to "warn" to strip everything
// but console.error, and any other truthy value to strip everything but console.warn and console.error.
// This defaults to "normal" (strip all but warn and error) if not provided.
stripConsole: 'all',

// The default selector engine is not included by default in a dojo.js build in order to make mobile builds
// smaller. We add it back here to avoid that extra HTTP request. There is also a "lite" selector available; if
// you use that, you will need to set the `selectorEngine` property in `app/run.js`, too. (The "lite" engine is
// only suitable if you are not supporting IE7 and earlier.)
selectorEngine: 'acme',


//localeList:"en-gb,en-us,de-de,es-es,fr-fr,it-it,pt-br,ko-kr,zh-tw,zh-cn,ja-jp",

// Builds can be split into multiple different JavaScript files called "layers". This allows applications to
// defer loading large sections of code until they are actually required while still allowing multiple modules to
// be compiled into a single file.
layers: {
    // This is the main loader module. It is a little special because it is treated like an AMD module even though
    // it is actually just plain JavaScript. There is some extra magic in the build system specifically for this
    // module ID.
    'dojo/dojo': {
        // In addition to the loader `dojo/dojo` and the loader configuration file `app/run`, we are also including
        // the main application `app/main` and the `dojo/i18n` and `dojo/domReady` modules because, while they are
        // all conditional dependencies in `app/main`, we do not want to have to make extra HTTP requests for such
        // tiny files.
        include: [ 'dojo/i18n', 'dojo/domReady', 'app/main', 'app/run' ],

        // By default, the build system will try to include `dojo/main` in the built `dojo/dojo` layer, which adds
        // a bunch of stuff we do not want or need. We want the initial script load to be as small and quick to
        // load as possible, so we configure it as a custom, bootable base.
        boot: true,
        customBase: true
    },
},

// Providing hints to the build system allows code to be conditionally removed on a more granular level than
// simple module dependencies can allow. This is especially useful for creating tiny mobile builds.
// Keep in mind that dead code removal only happens in minifiers that support it! Currently, only Closure Compiler
// to the Dojo build system with dead code removal.
// A documented list of has-flags in use within the toolkit can be found at
// <http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/has.html>.
staticHasFeatures: {
    // The trace & log APIs are used for debugging the loader, so we do not need them in the build.
    'dojo-trace-api': 0,
    'dojo-log-api': 0,

    // This causes normally private loader data to be exposed for debugging. In a release build, we do not need
    // that either.
    'dojo-publish-privates': 0,

    // This application is pure AMD, so get rid of the legacy loader.
    'dojo-sync-loader': 0,

    // `dojo-xhr-factory` relies on `dojo-sync-loader`, which we have removed.
    'dojo-xhr-factory': 0,

    // We are not loading tests in production, so we can get rid of some test sniffing code.
    'dojo-test-sniff': 0
}
```

}

and here is the index.html inside src/

> NOTE: `build.sh` is responsible for removing the "isDebug" flag when
>   deploying to production. If you modify this flag at all, you will
>   break the build!

```html
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1, tlmSiblingOfDojo: 0, locale:'en_US', isDebug: 1" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<!-- Load the loader configuration script. Note that this module ID is hard-coded in build.sh in order to provide
     an optimised build that loads as few as one script for the entire application. If you change the name or
     location of this module, you will need to update build.sh too. -->
<script src="app/run.js"></script>
```

this is the generated index.html in dist/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/resources/app.css">
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <script data-dojo-config=
            "async: 1, tlmSiblingOfDojo: 0, locale:'en_US', deps:['app/run']" 
            src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I checked to make sure that dojo/nls/dojo_en-us.js exists and it is fine. I am stuck at this point, having no clue!

Any help to fix this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if you managed to fix this but the multipleDefine can be caused by the builder inserting module identifiers.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897480/dojo-build-1-7-built-packages-does-not-work/13136546#13136546

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your requires in *run.js* ?
Did you require "dojo/_base/config" there ?

[ just noticed the same error because I forgot it ;) ]

**from the docs:**

> It is important to note the distinction between dojoConfig and dojo/_base/config. dojoConfig is purely for input purposes—this is how we communicate configuration parameters to the loader and modules. During the bootstrap process, dojo/_base/config is populated from these parameters for later lookup by module code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with error

> multipleDefine

when trying to include greensock library to my dojo project.

The issue appears when another library outside dojo declared its own `define` function (in my case was TweenMax) as they clash with dojo loader.

A solution is to make sure dojo loader is called after your library or script which use a `define` function have loaded.

So dojo should be the latest in your script to load in the html `head`:

```
<head>
    <script src="yourLibrary.js"></script>
    <script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</head>
```

This problem is also visible using [jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106054/error-multipledefine-from-dojo-jquery-ui-conflict) and other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a note about this in the loader documentation (at the time of this response anyway).

> **multipleDefine**
>   AMD define was called referencing a module that has
>   already been defined. The most common cause of this problem is loading
>   modules via  elements in the HTML document. Use the loader;
>   don't use  elements. The second most common cause is passing
>   explicit module identifiers to define; don't do this either.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/loader/amd.html

Many libraries now implement UMD which will basically try to auto-detect the existence of an AMD loader. For example, Bootstrap - the popular front-end framework - implements UMD.

So the following example will work (note that bootstrap will load globally):

```
<script src="path/to/bootstrap.js"></script><!--UMD packaged library-->
<script src="path/to/dojo/dojo.js"></script><!--then dojo loader-->
```

but the second example below will not work, since the UMD code will detect the AMD loader and use that to register itself. This will trigger the multipleDefine error as per the documentation.

```
<script src="path/to/dojo/dojo.js"></script><!--dojo loader first-->
<script src="path/to/bootstrap.js"></script><!--then UMD library-->
```

If you want to load the library globally use the first example above and load it bofore the dojo loader. If you want to load the library as an AMD module, use the loader.

Comment: What could I do if I can only load bootstrap via Dojo's require?